# Make a Link completely invisible to admin after loggin

Tags: php, yii

Hello i am using yii framework, i have write the code in Layout/main.php as follows

```
 array('label'=>'Dashboard', 'url'=>array('/site/todays_task'),'visible'=>$user-checkAccess('Team Leader,employee')),
```

and in my Protected/component/WebUser.php code is as follows

```
public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array())
{
    if (empty($this->id)) 
    {
         // Not identified => no rights
         return false;
    }
    $role = $this->getState("Role");
    if ($role === 'admin') {
         return true; // admin role has access to everything
    }
    if (strstr($operation,$role) !== false) { // Check if multiple roles are available
         return true;
    }
         // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
         return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

So the dashboard link is visible to admin, also because admin has access to everything in webuser checkaccess method, I want to invisible that dashboard link to admin

Comment: admin has access to everything (that's what admin is for), and you can't deny access to that user. If you could, that would be a major security hole that any malware could use to keep you from removing it. (You're not writing that kind of malware, are you? There's no other reason I can think of where you would need to keep admin from accessing things.)

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. You should probably use an enumerator instead of strings, and use arrays instead of checking for substrings. If you must use strings, uses substr_count( ... ) > 0 instead of strstr.

Answer (score 0):

Write a second function to do just that, returning false for the admin part;

```
public function checkAccessNoAdmin($operation, $params=array())
{
    if (empty($this->id)) 
    {
         // Not identified => no rights
         return false;
    }
    $role = $this->getState("Role");
    if ($role === 'admin') {
         return false; // admin role has no access here
    }
    if (strstr($operation,$role) !== false) { // Check if multiple roles are available
         return true;
    }
         // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
         return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

then call that instead:

```
array('label'=>'Dashboard', 'url'=>array('/site/todays_task'),'visible'=>$user-checkAccessNoAmdin('Team Leader,employee'))
```

Comment: so check it as the accepted answer so that folks will answer yr questions in future, as Ryan mentioned above... if you never accept answers you will end up being ignored.